# Can I install Windows on a NVMe drive on a system that doesn't support NVMe boot?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, bootloader, nvme

I have a PC with an Asrock 970 Extreme3 (and AMD FX-8350) that I'm repurposing, and along with a fresh install of Windows 10 I'm looking at upgrading the storage. Though this is a decidedly last-generation system, I figure it still has at least a couple years of usable life.

The price of NVMe is pretty comparable to SATA SSDs, so if I can I'd rather buy an NVMe drive (and the relatively inexpensive PCIe x16 adapter). I'm also assuming that even though the motherboard is only PCI Express 2.0, I'll still get better performance from that compared to a SATA-connected SSD.

The problem is it doesn't appear this board/BIOS supports NVMe boot.

Is there a way to have, for example, a small SATA drive set as the boot drive, have the bootloader (whether Windows or GRUB or whatever) there, and boot into Windows on the main NVMe drive, with that drive still appearing as `C:`? What steps are necessary? Will the Windows installer support this?

Unfortunately I don't have the PCIe adapter nor an extra NVMe drive to experiment with, and I don't really want to buy them if this isn't even possible.

Comment: You won't be able to boot from an NVMe SSD unless you modify the BIOS/UEFI (or can find a already modified BIOS/UEFI online) to support NVMe boot. As with any custom modifications to computer components, your results may vary, and there may be things that could completely prevent it from working even if it "should". You're much better off just getting a new system, especially considering you wouldn't even be able to use the NVMe drive to its full potential if you only have PCIe 2.0.

Comment: Instead of purchasing a drive that is not supported, get a proper BIG drive and install Windows on one drive.  Windows on 2 drives inevitably cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

Working nvme boot modified BIOS for asrock 970 extreme3
https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-asrock-970-extreme3-slic-2-1?page=2